# R grid.draw different heights for the graphs

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

While drawing and aligning graphs with R, I encountered a problem with aligning the axis of the graph, which I solved by using the gtable package. I used the following solution to align my graphs perfectly.

```
gMain=ggplotGrob(main_graph)
gExpr=ggplotGrob(expr_graph)
grid.draw(rbind(gMain, gExpr, size="first"))
```

However, with rbind, the 2 graphs have equal heights. **I want the first graph to take about 80% of the space while the 2nd graph taking 20% (in terms of graph height). Is this possible with rbind?**

I am using rbind only because its a simple and elegant solution to align my axis, if i need to resort to other ways to solve the alignment problems in order to keep different heights, feel free to give suggestions!

The graph is in the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would approach it using the `gridExtra` package. 
Note that the use of `arrangeGrob` instead of `grid.arrange` lets you use the nice `ggsave` function.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

df1 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(15, 0, 3),
                  y=rnorm(15, 0, 3))

df2 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(15, 0, 3),
                  y=rnorm(15, 0, 3))


p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_path()+
  ylab("tall plot")

p2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  ylab("short plot")

p_both <- arrangeGrob(p1, p2, heights=c(8,2))
print(p_both)
```

[image: stacked plot]

Comment: with grid.arrange the axes aren't properly aligned

Comment: Hi yap, the axis are not properly aligned as the graph u showed above! any other solutions...